# What does a magical sensor look like?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

As the DM, I am supposed to describe to my players everything they see and hear.

One of my players can see invisible things and monsters using [*see invisibility*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/see-invisibility).

What does the invisible magical sensor created via [*clairaudience-clairvoyance*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/clairaudience-clairvoyance) look like?

Comment: I edited your question a little bit for clarity, and to add links.  Please feel free to revert it if you think I changed the question to not ask about the problem you're trying to solve.  I've also voted to close it as opinion-based.  Stack Exchange isn't a good site for idea generation or lists of suggestions, it's more for solving a specific, answerable problem.  If you were looking for examples in the rulebooks, we might be able to help you but you'd be better suited going to a [forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449/3195) for getting lists of ideas.

Comment: I changed the question to not ask for opinions, and just ask what it looks like.

Comment: Reminder: comments are for clarifying content, not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead. Prior comments containing answers have been removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### GM's Choice

Since it is not explicitly stated what the magical sensor looks like, it is up to the GM to decide what it looks like if it is even visible at all.

One of the somatic components for the spell is a Glass Eye, so it would make sense to me if it appeared as a floating glass eye. The spell also specifically states that the sensor can be rotated to look around, which is a thing that eyes can do.

Ultimately, unless it is mentioned somewhere other than that specific spell description, it is up to the GM to decide what it looks like.